# Stop route loading on first request to Angular app

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my app, someone can select a language from a select list, and it updates some translations on the page.  It also updated the `$location.path()` to be `/:language`.  However, I don't have any special views.  It's a very simple application.  I have the URL updating and all that working fine.  However, if I come to the application not on the root path, such as `/spanish`, I get the error `Cannot GET /spanish`.  I want to be able to use whatever language the user decides come to the app with.  How can I use the param on load?  I am communication between controllers using `$rootScope.$broadcast`.  So I can't use `$routeProvider` to setup routes since the controllers and views controlling the page do not change at all.

**app.js**

```
angular
  .module('howToCussInApp', ['ngRoute'])
  .config(function($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  });
```

**selector.js**

```
angular.module('howToCussInApp')
  .controller('SelectorController', function ($rootScope, $scope, Translation, $location) {
    $scope.languages = [];

    Translation
      .get()
      .then(function(response) {
        $scope.languages = Object.keys(response.data);
        $scope.currentLanguage = $location.path().slice(1) || $scope.languages[0];
        $scope.update();
      });

    $scope.update = function() {
      $location.replace().path('/' + $scope.currentLanguage);
      $rootScope.$broadcast('languageUpdated', $scope.currentLanguage);
    };
  });
```

**translation.js**

```
angular.module('howToCussInApp')
  .controller('TranslationController', function($scope, Translation) {
    $scope.languageData = {};
    $scope.currentLanguage = '';

    Translation
      .get()
      .then(function(response) {
        $scope.languageData = response.data;
      });

    $scope.$on('languageUpdated', function(event, data) {
      $scope.currentLanguage = data;
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, this was unrelated to Angular.  The Grunt server that is created with the Angular Yeoman generator for some reason was throwing the 404, not Angular.